# slicing array based on selection masks

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

Given two arrays:

```
double[] a = new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
bool[] b = new bool[]{true, false, true};
```

Is there an easy way to select in `a` based on `b`? In R and other scripting languages you would say:

```
a[b]
```

to get `{1.0, 3.0}`. I can not figure out if there is a clean (no explicit loops involved) way to do this in C#. Maybe I should organise my data differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using LINQ:

```
double[] a = new double[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}; 
bool[] b = new bool[]{true, false, true}; 
var result = a.Where((item, index)=>b[index]);
```

Comment: wrong usage. Where is condition? It will give only make a copy of b in result.

Answer (score 6):

Use LINQ `Zip` method, e.g.:

```
a.Zip(b, (i, j) => new {i, j}).Where(x => x.j).Select(x => x.i)
```

Comment: Nice approach, did not know about the Zip method.

Answer (score 4):

There's also this more traditional LINQ approach:

```
b.Select((f, i) => f ? i : - 1).Where(i => i != -1).Select(i => a[i]);
```